OAuth2 issue: app doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure
I have configured my app on Google Cloud Platform.
Checked and rechecked redirect_uri
I have confirmed my Domain on Google console.
This is my implementation:
Using: @react-oauth/google to render the Google authorization screen.
I receive a successful response:
{
 code: '4/0AVG7etc', 
 scope: 'email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/au…le  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 
 authuser: '2', 
 hd: 'abc.com', 
 prompt: 'consent'
}

On my backend I POST:
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
{
    "code": "4/0AVG7etc",
    "client_id": "78....apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret": "...",
    "redirect_uri": "https%3A//example.com/oauth2callback",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code"
}

This returns:
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "\nYou can&#39;t sign in to this app because it doesn&#39;t comply with Google&#39;s OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.\n\nYou can let the app developer know that this app doesn&#39;t comply with one or more Google validation rules.\n  "
}

I have reverted to Testing mode.
I have configured my app on Google Cloud Platform.
Checked and rechecked redirect_uri.
I have confirmed my Domain on Google console.
I expected to be able to exchange the code for a token.
